# How to fit data when SSE is unreliable

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to estimate the parameter $\theta$ in the following problem.

I generate some **noiseless data** using: $Y ^{-\theta} = X_1 ^{-\theta} + X_2 ^{-\theta}$, where theta_real is set to a random number from 2 to 5 (my run for this data pulled a value of 4).

```
#Create some data
theta_real = sample(2:5,1)
X2 = sample(10:100, 100, replace=TRUE)
X1 = sample(10:100, 100, replace=TRUE)
Y <- (log(1/((X1^(-theta_real) + X2^(-theta_real))))/log(theta_real))
df <- data.frame(Y,X2,X1)
```

I attempt to estimate theta using nls2 in R:

```
require(nls2)

#For later flexibility
f_form <- function(x,theta) {x^-theta}

#Model Formula
fo <- f_form(Y,theta) ~ ((f_form(X1,theta) + f_form(X2,theta)))

#Evaluate 1000 different values
grid_length = 1000
st1 <- expand.grid(theta = seq(-10, 10, len = grid_length))
res <- nls2(fo,data=df, start=st1,algorithm="brute-force")
summary(res)
```

The result:

```
Formula: f_form(Y, theta) ~ ((f_form(X1, theta) + f_form(X2, theta)))

Parameters:
      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
theta    10.00       6.48   1.543    0.126

Residual standard error: 2.037e-09 on 99 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 1000 
Achieved convergence tolerance: NA
```

While minimizing SSE, theta gets driven to greater and greater negative values. (Notice that the estimate of $\theta = 10$ although the variable theta_real was sampled from the range 2 to 5. For whatever search bounds chosen, this method will always select the greatest theta.) This is because nls2 is minimizing sum square error, and as theta gets modified, the left-hand side of the equation gets transformed leading to the minimization of the SSE.

So how do you find the true $\theta$? Is there a way to minimize SSE relative to the range of values? Or a way to minimize according to correlation in the residuals?

Notes:

I've found that for the currently specified problem, using the inverse function helps, but what if the function is non-invertible (or has no closed form solution or some other issue preventing me from using the inverse)?

I also asked this question slightly differently [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154372/fitting-a-nonlinear-function-where-the-target-and-predictors-are-transformed-by) but it got closed due to ambiguity so I'm asking a different question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, because I'm not really understanding the question. Obviously, you would do a regression with $Y = (X_1^{-\theta} + X_2^{-\theta})^{-1/\theta}$ in this specific example. Of course, the documentation warns explicitly that `nls` shouldn't be used (and won't converge) with artificial zero-noise data.

If "the function is non-invertible" you need to give a specific example, because there is no universal solution to the problem.

Your formula for calculating `Y` is wrong. Either use

```
Y <- exp(log(1/((X1^(-theta_real) + X2^(-theta_real))))/(theta_real))
```

or (easier) from above

```
Y <- (X1^(-theta_real) + X2^(-theta_real))^(-1/theta_real)
```

Then you should absolutely not use `nls2` here. It is intended for solving formulas of the form `y ~ f(X)`. I'm astonished that it works at all, but the statistical output of `summary` cannot be trusted.

You are doing a simple grid search, which is easy to code in R:

```
res1 <- sapply(unlist(st1), function(th) {
  c(th, sum((f_form(df$Y, th) - (f_form(df$X1, th) + f_form(df$X2, th)))))
})

plot(res1[1,], log10(res1[2,]), type = "l")
```

[image: resulting plot]

And there you see a nice local minimum of the SSE.

You could now scale the SSE:

```
res1 <- sapply(unlist(st1), function(th) {
  c(th, sum(((f_form(df$Y, th) - (f_form(df$X1, th) + f_form(df$X2, th)))/f_form(df$Y, th))^2) )
})

plot(res1[1,], log10(res1[2,]), type = "l")
```

[image: resulting plot]

```
res1[, which.min(res1[2,])]
#[1] 3.993994e+00 4.095345e-05
```

And of course, you could then use a "real" optimizer.